# Need some clearance on how to write this program

Tags: c

I'm reading "C programming a modern approach 2nd edition"

One of the exercises is to write a program, where given in input, breaks down the input and shows how many $20 bills are used, $10, $5 and $1. It says
"To find how many $20 can be used, divide the total by 20, then reduce the amount by the total value of the $20 bills, repeat for the others"

So, this is what I had so far:

```
int main() {

    int amount, final, twenty, ten, five, one;

    printf("Enter the amount you'd like to use: ");
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    twenty = amount / 20;
    final = amount - (20 * twenty); // Amount is now 13

    ten = final / 10;
    final = 1 * ten;

    five = final / 5;
    final = 5 * five;

    one = final / 1;
    final = 1 * one;

    printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twenty);
    printf("$10 bills: %d\n", ten);
    printf("$5 bills: %d\n", five);
    printf("$1 bills: %d\n", one);


    return 0;
 }
```

So what I did was:

93 / 4 = 4.65 but truncated it to 4. 4 * 20 = 80 and did 93 - 80, which left me with 13. Now following these instructions, I encounter something wrong. I try the same thing but with $10 bills. 13 / 10 = 1.3 but truncated it to 1. 1 * 10 = 10 13 - 10 = 3 and I don't know how to implement it. The arithmetic in "final" I thought should follow the same setup as the first one:

> amount - (20 * twenty) // Amount is now 13

but no dice.

I honestly have been at this for 3 hours, and I just can't do it, would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Wow, already a downvote, tips on how to make this post more HQ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ten = final / 10;
final = 1 * ten;
```

Here is the logic error. It should be

```
ten = final / 10;
final -= ten * 10;
```

and 5, 1 has similar problem.

Comment: Ugh, my horrible logic skills defeat me once again :( Thanks for the response, I had -= the first time, but the multiplication was wrong

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each of your individual number checks should actually be in the form of

```
noOfNUMBERBills = final / NUMBER;
final %= NUMBER;
```

Where NUMBER is 5, 10 or 20

Read up on modulo (%) right now, you are going to need it a billion time in your programming career.